# Civicrm - Add SPF Record, All Emails are going to spam,

Tags: drupal

All of my civicrm email's are going to spam.
do i have to add SPF records for it? and if yes what it would be?

For more details:
https://www.screencast.com/t/hG2xCuBuE

Comment: This is more of a DNS question than a CiviCRM question, unless i'm completely misunderstanding it. Looks like you're on namecheap for causenow.org - check this link first: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/317/2237/how-do-i-add-txtspfdkimdmarc-records-for-my-domain.

Answer (score 2):

In gmail, click on the down arrow in the top right corner of the email and click Show Original. Then search for the text 'Authentication-Results' and see what it says (and add it to your answer if you like).

That should give you a clue as to why gmail thinks it is Spam and help you decide what action to take.

Aside: if you haven't done so already, marking the mail as not spam in gmail will help prevent emails going into the spam *on your account*. I'm not sure of the affect it has on other gmail accounts (probably minimal) but that might be useful for you, if just while you are getting set up.

Comment: While this may be helpful for testing, please do set up SPF and DKIM records for your server following the link for namecheap. Without them, your mails will go to spam for almost all clients, not just gmail. I'm sure marking mail as not spam factors into Googles algorithm but it won't take mails from other inboxes out of spam if you don't have SPF set up

Comment: Agree with that. My main point is that they should see what it says and take appropriate action. The marking as not spam was just an 'aside'.